# Excel macro does not rename data series if triggered via ole

Tags: excel, vba, ole

I have a Excel macro that creates some charts and assigns the series data ranges and series names like

```
Dim srsIdx
For Each srs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
   srs.xValues = ...
   srs.name = "series_name " & seriesIdx
   srsIdx = srsIdx + 1
```

(just a small part of the macro)

Works fine if I trigger the macro from the editor or a push button within the workbook, but if I trigger it via OLE the names are not changed but the data ranges and everything else like textboxes, headlines, etc. is as expected.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Tested it with python's `win32com` package and a customer software with OLE interface. Same results.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I set the name like shown above or via `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Item(item_index).Name`

Comment: Strangely enough, it was a chart template that was copied. The curves in this chart could not be renamed. If they were deleted and new curves were created, they could be renamed.
However, the different behavior when executing directly from Excel and executing via OLE could be observed reproducibly.
(Therefore no answer to this question.)